# can a file in a cvs be made readonly?

Tags: permissions, cvs

We would like to protect a configuration file in our project, from being committed by most developers (but leave it readable for everybody).
Is there a way to set this kind of permissions in CVS?
If not possible, just making it readonly for everybody will be good enough

Comment: Relevant indeed, thanks, but there is no satisfactory answer there

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent users from committing file. You can add a regex to the commitinfo file. You match the directory the file lives and specify a program that return non-zero if the file that is not allowed to be committed is in the argument list.

http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.11.23/cvs_18.html#commitinfo